# syntax of pdBlocked to specify covariance matrix in mixed-effects model nlme

Tags: r, covariance, mixed-models, nlme

I have a mixed-effects model and I want to drop some of my correlations in my random-effects covariance matrix to reduce my dof. To do this I think I should use `pdBlocked` but can't get the correct syntax to get specifically what I want.

Example code:

```
library(nlme)
m3 <- lme(distance ~ age +I(age^2) + I(age^3), data = Orthodont, 
           random = list(Subject = pdBlocked(list(~ age,~0 + I(age^2),~0+I(age^3)))))
```

which gives the following covariance matrix:

```
getVarCov(m3)
Random effects variance covariance matrix
            (Intercept)      age         I(age^2)                     I(age^3)
(Intercept)      5.2217 -0.30418 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000000000000000
age             -0.3042  0.04974 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000000000000000
I(age^2)         0.0000  0.00000 0.00000000003593 0.00000000000000000000000000
I(age^3)         0.0000  0.00000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000000000002277
  Standard Deviations: 2.285 0.223 0.000005994 0.000000000004772
```

This is close to what I want but not quite. I would like to keep the correlation between `I(age^3)` and `intercept`, `age` zero but allow a correlation with `I(age^2)`. Something like this:

```
getVarCov(m3)
Random effects variance covariance matrix
            (Intercept)      age         I(age^2)                     I(age^3)
(Intercept)      5.2217 -0.30418 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000000000000000
age             -0.3042  0.04974 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000000000000000
I(age^2)         0.0000  0.00000 0.00000000003593 a_value
I(age^3)         0.0000  0.00000 a_value          0.00000000000000000000002277
  Standard Deviations: 2.285 0.223 0.000005994 0.000000000004772
```

also for this scenrio

```
getVarCov(m3)
    Random effects variance covariance matrix
                (Intercept)      age         I(age^2)                     I(age^3)
    (Intercept)      5.2217 -0.30418 c_value          b_value          
    age             -0.3042  0.04974 d_value          0.00000000000000000000000000
    I(age^2)         c_value d_value 0.00000000003593 a_value
    I(age^3)         b_value 0.00000 a_value          0.00000000000000000000002277
      Standard Deviations: 2.285 0.223 0.000005994 0.000000000004772
```

I'm just not sure how to make a flexible covariance matrix to able to pick which ones are zero. These links were very helpful but still cant figure it out exactly
http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87050/dropping-term-for-correlation-between-random-effects-in-lme-and-interpretting-su?rq=1

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the `age^2` and`age^3` terms together in a single term seems to do it.

```
m4 <- lme(distance ~ age +I(age^2) + I(age^3), data = Orthodont, 
          random = list(Subject = pdBlocked(list(~ age,
                                                 ~0 + I(age^2)+I(age^3)))),
          control=lmeControl(opt="optim"))
getVarCov(m4)
## Random effects variance covariance matrix
##             (Intercept)       age    I(age^2)    I(age^3)
## (Intercept)     5.00960 -0.225450  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
## age            -0.22545  0.019481  0.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
## I(age^2)        0.00000  0.000000  4.1676e-04 -1.5164e-05
## I(age^3)        0.00000  0.000000 -1.5164e-05  5.5376e-07
##   Standard Deviations: 2.2382 0.13957 0.020415 0.00074415
```

I don't think there's any way to construct your second example (`age` and
`age^3` uncorrelated, all other correlations non-zero) with `pdBlocked` - there's no way to re-arrange the order of terms (rows/columns of the matrix) so that this matrix is block diagonal. You could *in principle* write your own `pdMatrix` class, but that would not be super-easy ...

I started to figure out how to do this in `lme4`, which has a modular design that would let you do this *slightly* more easily, but discovered an additional problem with your model; it's overdetermined for this data set (I don't know if it is for your real data set).  Because the `Orthodont` data set only has 4 observations per subject, fitting 4 random-effect values per individual (intercept plus 3 polynomial values) gives you a model where the random-effects variances are confounded with the residual variance (which can't be removed from these models). If you try, `lme4` gives you an error.

However, if you still really want to do this, you can override the error (DANGER WILL ROBINSON!) You first have to do some linear algebra, multiplying the lower-triangular Cholesky factor [which is the way that `lme4` parameterizes the variance-covariance matrix] to convince yourself that the `Cov(age,age^3)` is equivalent to `theta[2]*theta[4]+theta[5]*theta[7]`, where `theta` is the vector of elements of the Cholesky factor (lower-triangular, column-first order). Thus we can do this by fitting a 9-parameter model instead of the full 10-parameter model, with `theta[7]` set equal to `-theta[2]*theta[4]/theta[5]` ...

```
lf <- lFormula(distance ~ age +I(age^2) + I(age^3) +
                 (age+ I(age^2) + I(age^3)|Subject), data = Orthodont,
               control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore"))
devfun <- do.call(mkLmerDevfun,lf)
trans_theta <- function(theta)
  c(theta[1:6],-theta[2]*theta[4]/theta[5],theta[7:9])
devfun2 <- function(theta) {
  return(devfun(trans_theta(theta)))
}
diagval <- (lf$reTrms$lower==0)
opt <- minqa::bobyqa(fn=devfun2,par=ifelse(diagval,1,0)[-7],
             lower=lf$reTrms$lower[-7])
opt$par <- trans_theta(opt$par)
opt$conv <- 0
m1 <- mkMerMod(environment(devfun), opt, lf$reTrms, fr = lf$fr)
VarCorr(m1)
```

However, I would suggest you think carefully about whether it makes sense to do this.  I don't think you will actually gain very much in terms of precision/power from dropping terms in this way (in general, apparent gains in hypothesis-testing power derived from *post hoc* model simplification are illusory - see Harrell *Regression Modeling Strategies*) unless you have mechanistic or subject-based reasons to expect this particular covariance structure, I don't think I would bother.

Comment: Interesting. When I ran my unstructured model, I had very low correlations <0.1 (in the cells I wanted to make zero) while the others were >0.5. Even if they are extremely small would you leave them in? Could you equally say there is harm in taking them out? Just for my own sake would you know the required syntax for my second scenario above? Thanks

Comment: Isn't your second scenario just the full (unstructured) model, i.e. `random = ~ 1 + age + I(age^2)+I(age^3)` ?

Comment: No, `age` and `I(age^3)` are not correlated

Comment: Brilliant answer. Not as straight forward as I thought. I have a much larger dataset ~50 readings per individual, ~1000 individuals so dont have the same issue. Will look into this but thinking it may not be necessary anymore with your reference to Harrell. Have the book, must find the reference! Thanks

Comment: When counting the number of random effect values, why did Ben say 4 random effect values per ind? The first scenario has also cov btw intercept and age. Other scenarios has even more cov params. Should cov parameters be counted when determining if the model is overdetermined?

Comment: there are 4 random effect *values* (intercept, linear, quad, cubic terms, as I said in my answer) per individual.  This is different from the number of RE *parameters* required to define the covariance matrix of the values ...